# How to send textaera value through ajaxlink in yii?

Tags: php, yii

```
<?php echo CHtml::textArea('comment', '', array('id' => 'comment')) ?> </td>
 <td colspan="2">
 <?php
    echo CHtml::ajaxLink('<i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i>', Yii::app()->createUrl("ticket/AddComment", array("ticketId" => $ticketDetails->id,"comment"=>'$(#comment).val()')), array(), array('class' => 'btn btn-primary','title'=>'Accept'));
 ?>
```

but inside controller I didn't get the value of comment. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
    '<i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i>',
    array('ticket/AddComment'),
    array(
        // Point data here
        'data' => 'js:{comment:$("#comment").val()}',
    )
);
```

Comment: can i redirected to a page after i completed my ajax action?

Comment: yes. you can add `'success'` option after `'data'`. `'success'=>'function(html){ location.href="url here"; }'`